# Sum over partition but only as a running total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem.

[image: Current Output]

The correct values should be like this:

[image: Correct output]

The 9/13 data should have the orig_target_qty - sum(of 9/13/ exec_qty)

I want the difference between the 700,000 - sum of the total in the left box. I am partitioning the values by the ticker but the addition of 700k  + 100k - sum (of exec qty) should give me the correct result but for some reason I am getting the value short 100k because of the previous set of records that have 100k.

Any thoughts on why I'm doing this wrong? I have syntax wrong somewhere.

Comment: Can you please show us a table with the results you would like to have.
Also please use the column definitions when referring to them, as it is not clear what you want here.

Comment: *"I have syntax wrong somewhere."* If you have an attempt, include it in the question. We can't tell you why what you have isn't working if you don't include it. Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to show us the code and sample data. As the question stands it is too confusing.